# AWS RDS Serverless error: Set vpc security group for the DB Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, aws-serverless

##### `aws rds create-db-instance`

```bash
aws rds create-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier dashboard-db-instance-22-1 \  
    --db-instance-class db.serverless \
    --engine aurora-postgresql \
    --engine-version 14.6 \
    --availability-zone us-east-1a \
    --db-subnet-group-name default \
    --vpc-security-group-ids <SG-001> <SG-002> \
    --no-publicly-accessible \
    --db-cluster-identifier dashboard-db-instance-22
```

###### ERROR

```bash
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set vpc security group for the DB Cluster.
```

I've been searching around and still having trouble understanding the VPC mixup here. Thank you for any insights into the issue.

I've searched for where the VPCs are trying to line up and am not finding the disconnect. I've used my default VPC and let it create new VPCs and SGs with no luck.

[image]

If I leave out the VPC and SG paramters it works but is not in the VPC I'm hoping for:

```bash
aws rds create-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier dashboard-db-instance-1111-1 \
    --db-cluster-identifier dashboard-db-instance-1111 \
    --engine aurora-postgresql \
    --db-instance-class db.serverless
```

Comment: I think the error is clear: "Set vpc security group for the DB Cluster.". Did you try that?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, yes I've been looking. I updated my question showing some of what I've checked so far.

Comment: The security group for the instances inside your cluster are defined by the VPC security groups of your cluster, so you define the security group at cluster level.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @palvarez.

I was able to create the cluster with the right VPC via "cloning" with this command:

```bash
aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time \
    --source-db-cluster-identifier dashboard-db-instance \
    --db-cluster-identifier dashboard-db-instance-2222 \
    --restore-type copy-on-write \
    --use-latest-restorable-time \
    --db-subnet-group-name default-vpc-<VPC-ID>
```

and then add a DB Instance to it with:

```bash
aws rds create-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier dashboard-db-instance-3333-2 \
    --db-cluster-identifier dashboard-db-instance-3333 \
    --engine aurora-postgresql \
    --db-instance-class db.serverless \
    --db-subnet-group-name default-vpc-<VPC-ID>
```

*NOTE: The "cloned" db cluster has to have the desired VPC to begin with.